# Find the CDF from the PDF.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given this PDF find the value for k and find the CDF.

[image: problem]

To find k I did this: **1 = $\int_1^3 (k)(x-1)$ dx** and solving for k I got **1/2**.

Then to start solving for the CDF I did this:

$\int_0^x t^2$ dt = **t^3/3** evaluated at **x** and **0** and I got **x^3/3**

$\int_1^x (1/2)(t-1)$ dt = **(1/2)(t^2/2 - t)** evaluated I got **(1/4)(x-1)^2** but I now have to add in the prior integral at **F(1)** which equals **1/3** so I get **(1/4)(x-1)^2 + 1/3**

$\int_3^x (1/12)$ dt = **(1/12)(t)** evaluated I got **(1/12)(x-3)** but now I have to add in the prior integral at **F(3)** which equals **4/3**...but I thought that the probability had to add up to **1** in total? So why am I already at **4/3**? Can someone help point out where I went wrong?

Comment: The integral over the entirety of $f(x) = 1$. Not just one part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For finding $k$: Use $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1.$$

For finding CDF, $F(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$: Use $$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(y) dy. $$

Answer (score 1):

To find $k$, note that the CDF is $$F(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & : & x < 0 \\[1ex] \displaystyle\int_0^x s^2\operatorname d s &:& 0\leq x<1 \\\displaystyle \int_0^1 s^2\operatorname d s+\int_1^x k(s-1)\operatorname d s & :& 1\leq x< 3 \\\displaystyle \int_0^1 s^2\operatorname d s+\int_1^3 k(s-1)\operatorname d s +\int_3^x\tfrac 1{12}\operatorname d s&:& 3\leq x< 5 \\\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^2\operatorname d x+\int_1^3 k(x-1)\operatorname d x + \int_3^5 \tfrac 1{12}\operatorname d x &:& 5\leq x\end{cases}$$

And that *only* the last part must equal one.   So solve *that* for $k$.

$$\begin{align}1 ~&=~ \int_0^1 x^2\operatorname d x+\int_1^3 k(x-1)\operatorname d x + \int_3^5 \tfrac 1{12}\operatorname d x \end{align}$$